# Internal A Href link not working on website while external links using same class work without an issue

Tags: html

I have an internal link that does not appear to work.

I have two external linked directly above it with the same code simply with the url changed to reflect the correct location in my file structure:

```html
<h5 align="left"><a class='btn btn-link' href="https://www.ruok.org.au">R U OK Day</a></h5>

    <h5 align="left"><a class='btn btn-link' href="./otherpages/learningdevelopment.html">Learning and Development Portal</a></h5>
```

The second link when hovering over it reflect the correct file path (I have 1 folder within the group called "Other Pages" and there is only only other .html in that folder being "learningdevelopment"), however when I click on the link... nothing happens.

The external link above works perfectly fine, they are the same class etc so I cannot see a CSS issue being the problem, to be safe however, I deleted all the CSS and simply used HTML and same problem occurred.

I have tried moving the file to top level directory rather then my other pages file, same issue clicking does nothing (even without CSS).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try removing "dot" ?

Comment: Yep, link still does not click, if it were simply a mislabelled href it should still click and take me to a page not found or something, but it doesn't even click!

Comment: have you tried to change the link of the 2nd `<a href>` to the first? I mean replace the link and put the first link.+

Comment: Yep, all external links work fine, the second I point it internally, even with file:/// the link behaviour changes and no longer clicks. Quite frustrating.

Comment: Hmm... last, try removing both "dot" and "backslash"

Comment: Still doesn't work. I wonder if its an issue with visual studio code build. I'll develop the website soon onto my apache and see if I still have the issue.